# How to prevent a save without having cropped an image with imgAreaSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) plugin to let users crop an image. I would like to prevent that a user hits the save button without having cropped the image. I'm looking for a solutation in javascript instead of checking server side if the image has been cropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the samples in imgAreaSelect API:

```
$('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
    onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
        alert('width: ' + selection.width + '; height: ' + selection.height);
    }
});
```

just check if `selection.width` and `selection.height` are `> 0`